# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration for NodeJS

Tags: eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I am encountered with following errors on my pom.xml.

Error1:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:
>   com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.29-SNAPSHOT:install-node-and-npm
>   (execution: install node and npm, phase: generate-sources)

Error2:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.29-SNAPSHOT:npm
>   (execution: npm install, phase: generate-sources)

However, when i tried to fix it by select "Discover new m2e connector", it has landed with error *No catalog items are applicable*

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

you are using very specific maven plugin.
I think you can just configure m2e to ignore them. You can configure it directly in the pom.xml or at the workspace level. Both optiosn should be available from quickfix in the pom.xml editor.

Regards,